# How can I use a count without a group by function?

Tags: oracle

I need to use a case statement that counts the results to determine what’s outputted.

What I want to write is
when a_code returns more than 1 value output ‘n/a’ else output the a_code.

Here’s what I tried

```
select
case when COUNT(a_code) > 1 then 'n/a' else a_code end
from 
table_name
where b_code = 'abc';
```

this errors on ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
I understand that the error is because theres not a group by.

My issue is that by adding a group by like this

```
select
case when COUNT(a_code) > 1 then 'n/a' else a_code end
from 
table_name
where b_code = 'abc'
group by a_code;
```

Instead of counting the total a_code's returned and determining whether to 'n/a' or print a_code it counts duplicating a_codes and if there are duplicate a_codes it prints 'n/a'.

Any idea how I can write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the analytic `COUNT` function (rather than the aggregation function):

```sql
select case
       when COUNT(a_code) OVER () > 1
       then 'n/a'
       else a_code
       end AS a_code
from   table_name
where  b_code = 'abc';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a_code, b_code) AS
SELECT 'aaa', 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaa', 'abc' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| A_CODE |
| --- |
| n/a |
| n/a |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dkaKZHn7)

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data and desired result would help; meanwhile, see if this makes sense.

With such a sample data, first calculate number of rows you're interested in, and then use that value in final select:

```
SQL> with table_name(a_code, b_code) as
  2    (select '1', 'abc' from dual union all
  3     select '2', 'abc' from dual union all
  4     select '3', 'def' from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select count(*) cnt
  8     from table_name
  9     where b_code = 'abc'
 10    )
 11  select a.a_code, a.b_code, t.cnt,
 12    case when t.cnt > 1 then 'n/a' else a.a_code end result
 13  from table_name a cross join temp t;

A_CODE  B_CODE           CNT RESULT
------- ------- ------------ -------
1       abc                2 n/a
2       abc                2 n/a
3       def                2 n/a

SQL>
```

---

If there aren't at least two `abc`s:

```
SQL> with table_name(a_code, b_code) as
  2    (select '1', 'abc' from dual union all
  3     select '2', 'abx' from dual union all   --> was 'abc' before
  4     select '3', 'def' from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select count(*) cnt
  8     from table_name
  9     where b_code = 'abc'
 10    )
 11  select a.a_code, a.b_code, t.cnt,
 12    case when t.cnt > 1 then 'n/a' else a.a_code end result
 13  from table_name a cross join temp t;

A_CODE  B_CODE           CNT RESULT
------- ------- ------------ -------
3       def                1 3
2       abx                1 2
1       abc                1 1

SQL>
```